# i want to show and hide the given options on specific selections in the same form in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on and quiz application in C# and I have a query.

I have design form but I want to show and hide the given options on specific selections on the same form, how can I do that?

Following images explain my words I can not upload here because I am new.

http://bayfiles.net/file/VbpL/9DvsMw/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Use separate panels for each option. Hide/Show using its visible property

Comment: Kindly use http://imgur.com/ to upload the image.

Answer (score -1):

You can use nested if statements, [Jquery Hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [Show](http://api.jquery.com/show/). For User interface part.

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/EwNRJ/

```
 $('#target').show(500);
 $('#target').hide(500);
```

It is as simple as above code.
Select your control/controls call hide or Show.

If you are creating desktop app c# provides same [Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx) and [hide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx) methods.

Comment: friend it is a desktop base windows application. i am working in c# and you give the solution in c#

Comment: If you are creating desktop app c# provides same Show and hide methods. For links see the above answer...